# How to enable "host in the cloud" on existing Azure MVC ASP.NET web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, azure

I know you can enable it while you create the project here:

[image]

but is it possible to enable this when the project is already created ?

Comment: There's nothing to enable for an existing site. You just need to publish it to the cloud.

Comment: Oh, but what do you mean publish it to the cloud ? How do I do that

Comment: Right click your web application project, then click Publish. On the Profile step, choose Microsoft Azure App Service and hit Next.

Answer (score 3):

The Host in the cloud checkbox in this case will just allow you to select or create a Web App, and setup the publish profile for you. you can do this yourself:

You can do the yourself:
In  VS, Right click on solution -> Publish... -> Microsoft Azure App Service
You can select an existing Web App or create a new one right there.